# how to solve php error Undefined variable: id?

Tags: php, database

it is my code . it shows perfect output but one php error shown that is
it is my code . it shows perfect output but one php error shown that is

```
<tbody>
   <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $sum+= $row["Price"];
          $id .= $row["id"] . ",";
          echo "<tr><td>" . "#" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td><td>Rs " . $row["Price"] . "</td><td><a href='cart-remove.php?id={$row['id']}' class='remove_item_link'> Remove</a></td></tr>";
      }
      $id = rtrim($id, ", ");
      echo "<tr><td></td><td>Total</td><td>Rs " . $sum . "</td><td><a href='success.php?itemsid=" . $id . "' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td></tr>";
      ?>
</tbody>
```

> Undefined variable: id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: `$id = '';` use this before while loop or `$id = 0;`

Comment: `$id .= $row`   the `.` before `=` in `$id` suggests that are appending value to existing `$id`

Comment: use `implode()` and save id in an array

Comment: okk..got it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve your desired result as:

**Example:**

```
$idArray = array(); // initialize array
while () { // your while loop
$idArray[] = $row["id"]; // save id into an array
}
$id = implode(',', $idArray); // now you can use this variable as you need.
```

Here, i am saving `$id` into an array. then you just need to use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method.

By using this, you do not need to use `trim()` method to remove last comma `(,)`

Side Note: This is just an example to use `array` and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 2):

You try to concatenate the `$id` variable but you haven't set it anywhere so it is undefined. You simple have to define it before your while loop like:

```
<tbody>
<?
$id = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sum+= $row["Price"];
    $id .= $row["id"] . ",";
    echo "<tr><td>" . "#" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td><td>Rs " . $row["Price"] . "</td><td><a href='cart-remove.php?id={$row['id']}' class='remove_item_link'> Remove</a></td></tr>";
}
$id = rtrim($id, ", ");
echo "<tr><td></td><td>Total</td><td>Rs " . $sum . "</td><td><a href='success.php?itemsid=" . $id . "' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td></tr>";
?>
</tbody>
```

This will solve your issue but check @devpro answer. He is using a way more elegant solution and a better approach.